# VBA: Extract sentence being referenced by a footnote macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been using the code linked below to take info from a word document and create an new Excel document in which it inserts the footnote reference in the first column, the page on which the footnote appears in the second column and the text of the footnote in the third column.

I'd now like to add a forth column to the excel document that contains the sentence from the word document that the footnote references.

Can't figure it out, any help?

sorry if this is easy, VBA is not a language I know hardly at all!

[The Code I've Been Using](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/extract-footnotes-from-word-to-excel/867a60b0-16dd-4494-80ba-d8da8670cacd)

Comment: What have you tried on your own? `Reference` property of `Footnote` object returns a `Range` object of the reference marker itself, which you can then reference to the first (and only) paragraph object and lastly, its `Range.Text` property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.footnote.reference

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondWu! figured it out!

Comment: @ZarchMane Nice job! I think you can do it by using `fnote.Reference.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text` too. But you will need to remove the paragraph marker which I will probably set `aRange` to `fnote.Reference.Paragraphs(1).Range` then `aRange.SetRange aRange.Start, aRange.End -1`

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated code for all who are interested... I imagine this is mostly useful for people making research books and papers

````
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object
Dim xlsheet As Object
Dim i As Long, lognum As Long
Dim fnote As Footnote
On Error Resume Next
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    bstartApp = True
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
With xlsheet.Range("A1")
    .Offset(0, 0).Value = "Foonote Ref"
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Page"
    .Offset(0, 2).Value = "Footnote Text"
    .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Sentence"
    i = 1
    For Each fnote In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
            Set aRange = fnote.Reference
        aRange.MoveStart unit:=wdSentence, Count:=-1
        aRange.MoveEnd unit:=wdSentence
        .Offset(i, 0).Value = fnote.Index
        .Offset(i, 1).Value = fnote.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        .Offset(i, 2).Value = fnote.Range.Text
        .Offset(i, 3).Value = aRange.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next fnote
End With
xlapp.Visible = True
xlbook.Activate
Set xlapp = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xlsheet = Nothing
End Sub```
````